# how to propagate changes to all lists created from a custom template list

Tags: custom-list, list-template

This might be an easy question to answer but I'm still new to SharePoint 2010. Here's my problem.

I created a custom list that is used as a template, and I have a handful of lists that were created from this template list. I recently made some changes to the template and I want the changes to be propagated to the other lists that were created from the template. How do I do this? I know I can can manually add the changes to each lists but there are a handful of lists and it would be time consuming. I feel like there must be an easy way to do this and that microsoft must have provided an easy way of doing it.

Some of the changes I made are

- New items in the dropDown
- new rules to the fields using InfoPath
- new fields to the list

Thank you for reading. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no easy way of doing it. You may either have to propagate changes manually or by using custom code. There is a question about propagating content type changes which is similar to your question.
[Choice field changed - How to propagate the change down to all lists that used it?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22095/choice-field-changed-how-to-propagate-the-change-down-to-all-lists-that-used-i)